# jqGrid: fixed row

Tags: javascript, jqgrid

Is it possible to set a row on a fixed position? For example, we have now a total row, and we always want the total on top, after sorting etc.

Is there a plugin for this?

We have tried to do this in the onLoadComplete by redrawing the whole table like so:

```
var rowIDs = $(this).getDataIDs();
var rowID, columnID;
$(this).clearGridData(); 
for (rowID in rowIDs) {
  for (columnID in data.rows[rowID]) {
    $(this).addRowData(rowIDs[rowID], data.rows[rowID], (data.rows[rowID][columnID].first ? 'first' : null));
    break; // Only do this for the first column
  }
}
```

but that is bad for performance, we have thousands of rows.

after Oleg's comment:

The total row is just a row from our dataset. The dataset has this format:

Columns: 'Network', 'Clicks', 'Views'

```
data = [
  {
    'Network': {value:'Google'}, 'Clicks': {value:38392882}, 'Views':{value:3939922}
  },
  {
    'Network': {value:'Sanoma'}, 'Clicks': {value:177883}, 'Views':{value:39293}
  },
  ...
  ,
  {
    'Network': {value:'Total'}, 'Clicks': {value:993832732223}, 'Views':{value:3932293939}, 'first': true
  },
  ...

]
}
```

So we set in our datarow which row we want to have on top ('first':true).

By processing, we use that to set in on top of the table. Hopefully this is more understandable :)

Thanks in advance,

Eddy

Comment: I forget to mention that the usage of `addRowData` for every row of grid is really very slow method. I didn't understand from your question why you need to do this. You can ask new question where you post more code and explain exactly **why** you need this. Do you receive the data from the server as JSON data? Why jqGrid can not  fill the data direct? I am sure that one can find more effective method to fill the grid.

Comment: @oleg: yes we noticed that addRowData is very slow, thats why we wanted another solution. I took your advice and edited the question. Thank you.

Comment: what stay unclear for me is **how** the data from the dataset will be send to the client? Do you make an ajax call before filling jqGrid? Why you place the data in so strange form like `'Network': {value:'Google'}` instead of `Network:'Google'`? Why you set `first:true` as a part of the data? Do you have more then one item having `first:true`? In general you can easy create jqGrid having `gridview:true` and [localReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#array_data) which corresponds the structure of your data and use `data` parameter of jqGrid.

Comment: @oleg yes we do an ajax call (json request) to get the data from the server. The data is in this form so we can do some stuff per datacell: Network: {'value':827387,  benchmark:true, striong:(somecondition?true:false)} which are parsed by the formatters.

Comment: "datacell" say me not much, but if you get the data per ajax you can define [jsonReader](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data) parameter which will allow jqGrid to read the JSON data in the form which the server provide. So you can directly use `datatype:'json'` in the jqGrid and define the server `url` which provide the data. You can use additionally 'gridview:true' parameter of jqGrid which speed up the filling of grid additionally. So the data will be filled in the grid **at once** and all will work quickly.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The footer are placed in the div with the class "ui-jqgrid-sdiv" and it is placed typically below the div with the class "ui-jqgrid-bdiv" where the main grid contain are placed. So to move the footer on top of page you need to move the the footer div. Additionally you should place bottom border in the style which you need. The code could be like the following:

```
$('div.ui-jqgrid-sdiv').css({
    "border-bottom-style":"solid",
    "border-bottom-color":"#a6c9e2",
    "border-bottom-width":"2px"
}).insertBefore($('div.ui-jqgrid-bdiv'));
```

as the result you will receive
[image]

See the demo live [here](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TopFooter.htm).

Comment: nice option. We have data as objects and total is just a row form our dataset, which have to go through a lot of formatters, so I am not sure if I can do the same thing, but I will try. Thanks for your nice option.

Comment: @eddy147: You are welcome! As I wrote before I see many optimization potential in your code. You need just explain more exactly why you need to add the rows with `addRowData` in loop. If you have dataset on the server you can fill `userdata` in JSON response from the server and use `userDataOnFooter:true` in jqGrid which will place the data from `userdata` in th grid.