# jqgrid add fixed row

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, jqgrid

Is it possible to add a fixed row to grid instead of footer?

i want to add some additional information to grid like "transport charges = "
then the footer row

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In order to what you want, you need to move the footer div which is named 'ui-jqgrid-sdiv'. You can use some CSS to insert the div elsewhere in the grid. There is a good example of [this at this StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632506/jqgrid-fixed-row/5633492#5633492).