# is there a way to add a summary row to jqgrid treeview

Tags: jquery, jqgrid, treegrid, column-aggregation

i am using [jqgrid with the treegrid view](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:treegrid) and most of the columns are numbers that are aggregated up the tree.  The one missing piece is having a total row to aggregate the top level hierarchy.  Is there something built into jqgrid to support this or should be passed down the:

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Tree grid support footer row (see the second picture [here](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:how_it_works)) for tree grid in the same way like for the standard grid. If you calculate the content of the summary row on the server you can use `userdata` in the JSON input (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2820254/jqgrid-loading-data-into-the-footer-row/2820563#2820563)). If you want have custom formatting of the summary row or if you want to calculate the values for the summary row on the client you can use [footerData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:methods) method inside of `loadComplete` for example. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5121350/jqgrid-access-cell-data-while-it-is-being-edited/5129908#5129908) for an example.

The following simple [demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/LocalAdjacencyTreeWithFooter.htm) produce the output:
[image]

The changes in the original treegrid code are the following:

```
footerrow: true,
loadComplete: function () {
    $(this).jqGrid('footerData','set',
        {name:'TOTAL', num:"500", debit:"<i>Bla</i> Bla",
        credit:'20', balance:'<span style="color:red">-1000</span>'});
}
```

Comment: if i want to display just one value in the first td like for example  "Total: 2324", is it possible to set callspan for the that td?

Comment: @bigb: I think it should work, but you should don't forget to hide the next `<td>` element of the row. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5625325/how-to-merge-cells-in-jqgrid-4-0/5625959#5625959) for details.

Comment: and one more thing is it possible to do similar to `footerrow` but to display that in the top(first row)?

Comment: @bigb: Yes it's also possible. See my [old demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/TopFooter.htm) from [the answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5632506/jqgrid-fixed-row/5633492#5633492)

Comment: in my first comment i meant that i want to display just one td in `footer`, all the rest data rows staying the same. If i get the last `tr` after i call `grid.jqGrid('footerData','set',{name:'Total : ' + counter });` in `loadComplete` event, a am getting the last data `tr`  but not footer `tr`, so not sure how to get `footer` to modify, so probably i need to do that on some event after jqgrid nearly displayed.

Comment: @bigb: Sorry, but I don't understand you. You wrote "i want to display just one td in `footer`". What do you mean? The footer div has the same columns like the main grid. If the name of the last column is 'lastCol' you can set the test with `grid.jqGrid('footerData','set',{lastCol:'Total : ' + counter });`

Comment: i want to be able to modify the foooter, i want to group cells with callspan (for first cell i want to be able to say `callspan=N` for example) and than also i want to change background on that `td` because my first cell contains Id and it has background on that.

Comment: @bigb: OK, I understand. Try with this  `grid.closest("div.ui-jqgrid-view").children("div.ui-jqgrid-sdiv").find("table.ui-jqgrid-ftable tr.footrow")` to get the `tr` of the footer.